# Record count wrong in Report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I have a Matrix Report that is based on a Custom Report Type. The Custom Report Type has 3 levels: "A" records may or may not have "B" records and "B" records may or may not have "C" records.

[Report](http://imageshack.us/a/img339/15/tablerq.jpg)

The Report uses one B field on the left ("Name") and one B field on top ("Scheduled release Date"). B records without Cs now have a Record Count of 1 although there is definitely no record. What is shown in the table is an empty column.

[Chart](http://imageshack.us/a/img405/1310/chartm.jpg)
As a consequence of this the chart also shows wrong numbers. Any ideas? I want to have the empty B records also in the table and in the chart, but with the correct record count of Cs of zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [The Power of One](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tde), this really helped me build a number of reports. If I'm understanding your data model correctly, you'll want to add a new formula field to the C object, call it "Number_of_C__c" or something similar, the Formula should just be a Number with the value "1".

Then, if you update your reports to summarize by the "Number_of_C__c" field instead of RecordCount, Salesforce will automagically calculate the number of C records in that particular grouping, including zero. This will also fix the related Chart as well, provided that you update the Y-Axis to use the new field.

[image: Example Setup]

Comment: I use this on pretty much every object in my org.

Comment: Very cool solution, never heard of it!

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is a perfect solution for the problem!