# How do get the count of distinct or unique parent records in reports?

Tags: reporting

I am building a report on 2 objects with a parent child (MD) relationship.  How can i get the count of unique parents when i get the report filtered by some child objects field criteria.  There might be more than 1 child record after applying the condition.  How can i get a distinct/unique record count of the parent?

Comment: In a Summary report of Master with Child, applying a cross filter should let you filter on child records (further filtering using a subfilter on child records), and grouped by Parent (say Name) should give you unique count of Parent Records ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Power of One, as [mentioned by Salesforce](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tde) and discussed in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/record-count-wrong-in-report/4829).

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a campaign member report counting the Ultimate Parent accounts? Cannot do a cross-filter because some accounts may not have a Parent.