# How to eliminate duplicate records in a report?

Tags: reporting, person-accounts

I am using Person Accounts and have 2 custom objects: Ownership and Property.

The Ownership is a junction object and has 2 lookups: Account and Property.

I'd like to run a report with a filter, that gives me unique Accounts where House.Type = 'Maisonette'.

However when I run a report, I may get multiple Accounts because someone owns more than one Property which is a Maisonette.

Any help please?

Comment: Do you just want counts or to eliminate the duplicates all together?

Comment: Is it possible to do both? (in seperate reports at least?)

Comment: You can't remove the duplicates in the report; the report builder doesn't do distinct so I'd recommend Excel. For counting, see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8476/how-do-get-the-count-of-distinct-or-unique-parent-records-in-reports/8477

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, in SOQL you'd express your requirement more or less like that?

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Ownership__c WHERE Property__r.Type__c = 'Maisonette')
```

It's perfectly doable with a [cross filter](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_cross_filters.htm&language=en).

Let's say I want to see Accounts that have at least 1 Contact with title = Director:

[image]

Here's how it looks on the "run report" page (note the icon)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in the report builder; it is simply not that powerful. It would be possible query this data using a sub-query in Apex Code (e.g. if you wanted to use Visualforce), by post-processing the data in Excel, or by using a third-party reporting tool that supports this functionality; a list of the latter can be found on the AppExchange.

Comment: I respectfully disagree :)

Comment: @eyescream And I learnt something new. That'll teach me not to read the release notes each release.

Answer (score -1):

We have been using Excel and Access to handle this. They don't allow me to do the cool programming stuff here. :'(