# Activity history report

Tags: reporting, activities

I have a report that provides a count of activities by sales rep.
I need to modify this report to count only one record per account/company.  In short, our reps are required to make X number of calls per week and I want to only count records once per account/company.  If they 'log a call' for ABC 5 times during the week, I want to only count it once.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "[Power of one](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tde)" trick as explained in [How do get the count of distinct or unique parent records in reports?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8476/how-do-get-the-count-of-distinct-or-unique-parent-records-in-reports) and [Record count wrong in Report](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/record-count-wrong-in-report) questions (I'm not sure whether we should merge or leave it as standalone Q).

Create a numeric "Count of Accounts" formula on Account (value should be just "1") and try to make an "Activities with Accounts" report.

[image: Sample report]

There will be mismatch between Record count and your field which i think is what you're after.